# Get newest values by groups (for join)

Tags: mysql, max, left-join

i have two tables. In `xDATA` I have info about tasks and in `xSTATUS` I have progression of tasks.

It goes like this:

```
{xDATA}
ID|description|...
------------------
 1|...
 2|...
 3|...
```

Data in `xSTATUS` table are specified by timestamp:

```
{xSTATUS}
timestamp          |ID|status
--------------------------------
2015-03-22 12:22:33| 1|Added
2015-03-22 14:00:03| 1|Assigned
2015-03-23 08:00:00| 2|Added
2015-03-23 12:00:00| 1|Completed
```

For preview I want `ID`, `description` and newest `status`. Is there any way to get newest value (for ex. using `GROUP BY`)?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `left join` as

```
select 
xd.*,
st.status 
from xdata xd join xstatus st on st.id = xd.id 
left join xstatus st1 on st.id = st1.id 
and st.timestamp < st1.timestamp 
where st1.id is null ;
```

There are other techniques available for this, check here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html